# How would I hover only one specific element instead hovering two at the same time

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Right now I have it so when I hover one card it renders data for both cards like so:

[image: When I hover over one card it displays both card's data]

How could I refactor my code to make it so when I hover over one card it only displays that cards data? I know I can pass down the specific id of the card that I hover over but I'm not sure how to go about doing that exactly.

```
class Landing extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props)

        this.state = {
            hover: false,
            stats: [
                {
                    image: 'https://cdn.bulbagarden.net/upload/thumb/6/62/Sapphire_EN_boxart.png/250px-Sapphire_EN_boxart.png',
                    votes: 10745,
                    rating: 1601
                },
                {
                    image: 'https://www.zeldadungeon.net/wiki/images/2/25/Minish-Cap-Cover.jpg',
                    votes: 19345,
                    rating: 5670
                }
            ]

        }
    }

    handleMouseHover = (id) => {
        this.setState({
            hover: !this.state.hover
        })
    }

    renderCards = () => {
        return (
            <div className='card-carousel'>
                {this.state.stats.map(stat => {
                    return (
                        <Card
                            key={stat.id}
                            image={stat.image}
                            onMouseEnter={() => this.handleMouseHover(stat.id)}
                            onMouseLeave={() => this.handleMouseHover()}
                            renderVotesRatings={this.renderVotesRatings()}>
                        </Card>
                    )
                })}
            </div>
        )
    }


    renderVotesRatings = () => {
        if (this.state.hover)
            return (
                <>
                    {this.state.stats.map(stat => {
                        return (
                            <div className='stats-card' key={stat.id}>
                                <img src='https://i.imgur.com/rXfPua4.png'></img>
                                <h3>{stat.votes}</h3>
                                <img src='https://i.imgur.com/1aiORiI.png'></img>
                                <h3>{stat.rating}</h3>
                            </div>
                        )
                    })}
                </>
            )
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The code doesn't seem to be complete. However, I will tell you the general idea.
You should have each item as a separate component that has its own state like the following:

```
class Landing extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      stats: [
        {
          image:
            "https://cdn.bulbagarden.net/upload/thumb/6/62/Sapphire_EN_boxart.png/250px-Sapphire_EN_boxart.png",
          votes: 10745,
          rating: 1601
        },
        {
          image:
            "https://www.zeldadungeon.net/wiki/images/2/25/Minish-Cap-Cover.jpg",
          votes: 19345,
          rating: 5670
        }
      ]
    };
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="card-carousel">
        {this.state.stats.map(stat => {
          return (
            <CardItem
              key={stat.id}
              image={stat.image}
              votes={stat.votes}
              rating={stat.rating}
            />
          );
        })}
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

and create another file "card-item.js" for `CardItem` component

```
class CardItem extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      hover: false
    };
  }

  renderVotesRatings = () => {
    if (this.state.hover) {
      return (
        <div className="stats-card">
          <img src="https://i.imgur.com/rXfPua4.png" />
          <h3>{this.props.votes}</h3>
          <img src="https://i.imgur.com/1aiORiI.png" />
          <h3>{this.props.rating}</h3>
        </div>
      );
    }
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <Card
        image={this.props.image}
        onMouseEnter={() => this.setState({ hover: true })}
        onMouseLeave={() => this.setState({ hover: false })}
        renderVotesRatings={this.renderVotesRatings()}
      />
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: I set up my components like this instead and now it looks like this and I understand that each individual card component needs its own state for hover, but im not getting the hover state/its not recognized in the components section when i insert the CardItem component into my landing container. Do i need to also hold hover state in the landing container?

Comment: I can't understand why you aren't getting the hover state/its not recognized in the components section? Can you eloborate?

Comment: Sure so I have a parent container which is landing.jsx which I am importing my carditem component to, but from my understanding you can't pass individual state into the parent container, so if I have the hover state in my carditems component and im importing that component into my parent component it won't recognize the hover state i think? So thats why I say when i open up chrome dev tools and check my components section I can see all the props I have but I dont see the hover state itself.